# Auto Scramble Chrome Cube Lab?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am using Chrome Cube Lab to generate an interactive Rubik's Cube akin to what is found here: https://chrome.com/cubelab#experiment

I am successfully using the most basic install with just the cuber.js and cube.css to render the cube (downloaded here: https://www.rubiks.com/chrome-cube-lab).

I need a way to auto scramble the cube when it renders. There are multiple examples of cubes that can scramble when a button is clicked, etc. These are a bridge too far, including a myriad of things that I do not need (including solving the cube, revolving it, going back one step, etc.). My only need is for the cube to scramble and then function as-is with users being able to "play" with it as they please.

Answer (score 0):

You ever post a question that's been bugging you all day, then immediately find the answer in the ReadMe that you swore you read?

Anyway, there is a built in function that does this: cube.shuffle( 5 )

I have it firing on page load, but will likely call it via a button to give the user control over it.

Thanks, everyone.